# How to implement download pdf/docx file with downloadable link in DataTable columns

Tags: file, download, datatables, django-rest-framework

I'd like to download files from DataTable columns, HTML code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#sample').DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "/api/sample/?format=datatables",
            "columns": [
                {"data": "hospital_name"},
                {"data": "report_path", "render":function(data,type,row,meta){
                    return '<a href="{% url 'downloads' "'+data+'" %}">Download</a>'
```

The download always failed.Maybe there is something wrong with:
**return 'Download'**
How can I send "report_path" the views function downloads and trigger download correctly.

```
downloads in views.py:
def downloads(request, filename):
    file_pathname = filename
    with open(file_pathname, 'rb') as f:
        file = File(f)
        response = HttpResponse(file.chunks(),content_type='APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_pathname)
    return response

urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    url('^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url('$', views.index,name='htdbs'),
    url('htdbs/', include('htdbs.urls')),
    url(r'^downloads/(?P<filename>.*)$', views.downloads, name='downloads')
]
```

I put uploaded file in MEDIA_ROOT, seetings.py:

```
# media storage
MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:/uploads/'
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

in models.py the file:

```
report_path = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/%Y/%m/%d')
```

**so, How could I successfully download the uploaded pdf/docx file ?**

Comment: What happens when you click the Download link? Do you get a 404 or a 500 error or something else?

Comment: The file '+data+'.htm is downloaded automatically. And the content is exactly same as my htdbs.html. I could see the '+data+' is right full filepath with correct uploaded filename. like: localhost/uploads/2018/05/10/1234.pdf. But I got '+data+'.htm after click download link